# How to make Scrapy XmlFeed Spider Faster

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, scrapy

The xml feed I'm scraping has around thousand items. I'm wondering if there is a way to split the load or another method to significantly reduce run time. It currently takes two minutes to iterate all the xml within the link below. Any suggestions or advice is greatly appreciated.

Example: https://www.cityblueshop.com/sitemap_products_1.xml

```
from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider
from learning.items import TestItem
class MySpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = 'testing'
    allowed_domains = ['www.cityblueshop.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.cityblueshop.com/sitemap_products_1.xml'] 

    namespaces = [('n', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9')]
    itertag = 'n:url'
    iterator = 'xml'


    def parse_node(self, response, node):

        item = TestItem()
        item['url'] = node.xpath('.//n:loc/text()').extract()


        return item
```

Two minute run time for all items. Any ways to make it quicker using Scrapy?

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following spider locally:

```py
from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider

class MySpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = 'testing'
    allowed_domains = ['www.cityblueshop.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.cityblueshop.com/sitemap_products_1.xml']

    namespaces = [('n', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9')]
    itertag = 'n:url'
    iterator = 'xml'


    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        yield {'url': node.xpath('.//n:loc/text()').get()}
```

It takes less than 3 seconds to run, including Scrapy core startup and everything.

Please, ensure that the time is not spent somewhere else, e.g. in the `learning` module from which you import your item subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase CONCURRENT_REQUESTS, CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN, CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP, for example: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests-per-domain
But remember that besides high speed it can lead to lower success rate, like many 429 responses, bans, etc.

Comment: all that content is on the same page and its just parsing through it, it's just one request needed for the main xml page

Comment: Oops, my bad, misread. In this case yes, these settings are useless, sorry.